# TypeError: e is undefined in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Now I'm getting frustrated :( This is my very first attempt at using vue.js which after jQuery, is the second JS framework I'm learning since I came to this planet. I have the following HTML:

```js
var main = new Vue({
  el: ".main-content",
  data: {
    heading: "First Vue Page",
    usdamount: 0,
    currencies: [{
        label: "GBP",
        rate: 0.7214,
        value: 0
      },
      {
        label: "EUR",
        rate: 0.80829,
        value: 0
      },
      {
        label: "CAD",
        rate: 1.2948,
        value: 0
      }
    ]
  },
  computed: {
    updateCurrencies: function() {
      console.log(this.usdamount);
      var usd = parseFloat(this.usdamount);
      for (var i = this.currencies.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        this.currencies[i].value = this.currencies[i].rate * usd;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
<section class="main-content">
  <h1>{{ heading }}</h1>
  <input type="number" v-on:change="updateCurrencies" v-model="usdamount">
  <p class="cur-value" v-for="cur in currencies">
    <strong>{{ cur.label }}</strong>: {{ cur.value }}
  </p>
</section>
```

When I load the page everything works fine and I get a zero logged on the console. If I try to change the input I get:

```
TypeError: e is undefined
Stack trace:
we@https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue:6:26571
X@https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue:6:7441
...
```

I went to the part that is complaining and got even more lost. It's this function:

```
function we(t,e,n,r){(r||si).removeEventListener(t,e._withTask||e,n)}
```

I have no idea what's causing the error even after several attempts to change things and isolate the problem.

Comment: Have you installed the Vue developer extensions in Chrome? That usually helps check if Vue-side everything is ok.

Comment: I am far from a vuejs expert, but is the `computed` property not meant to be used for [computed properties](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html) based on what I have read on the docs, I think you need to move `updateCurrencies` to the `methods` property of your vue instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`computed` is for automatic recalculation whenever an involved data property from your VM changes. To attach a method to an event handler, use `methods` block:

```js
var main = new Vue({
  el: ".main-content",
  data: {
    heading: "First Vue Page",
    usdamount: 0,
    currencies: [{
        label: "GBP",
        rate: 0.7214,
        value: 0
      },
      {
        label: "EUR",
        rate: 0.80829,
        value: 0
      },
      {
        label: "CAD",
        rate: 1.2948,
        value: 0
      }
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    updateCurrencies: function() {
      console.log(this.usdamount);
      var usd = parseFloat(this.usdamount);
      for (var i = this.currencies.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        this.currencies[i].value = this.currencies[i].rate * usd;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
<section class="main-content">
  <h1>{{ heading }}</h1>
  <input type="number" v-on:change="updateCurrencies" v-model="usdamount">
  <p class="cur-value" v-for="cur in currencies">
    <strong>{{ cur.label }}</strong>: {{ cur.value }}
  </p>
</section>
```

Since you indeed have the case that data depends on `usdamount` and should be adjusted whenever that value changes, making `currencies` a computed property would be an even better approach:

```js
var main = new Vue({
  el: ".main-content",
  data: {
    heading: "First Vue Page",
    usdamount: 0,

  },
  computed: {
    currencies() {
      let cur = [{
          label: "GBP",
          rate: 0.7214,
          value: 0
        },
        {
          label: "EUR",
          rate: 0.80829,
          value: 0
        },
        {
          label: "CAD",
          rate: 1.2948,
          value: 0
        }
      ];
      for (var i = cur.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        cur[i].value = cur[i].rate * parseFloat(this.usdamount);
      }
      return cur;
    }

  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
<section class="main-content">
  <h1>{{ heading }}</h1>
  <input type="number" v-model="usdamount">
  <p class="cur-value" v-for="cur in currencies">
    <strong>{{ cur.label }}</strong>: {{ cur.value }}
  </p>
</section>
```

This way you don't have to implement a listener yourself and instead use Vue's mechanisms to update your data and DOM.

Comment: Added a second example with proper usage of `computed`. Notice also you  don't need the `v-on:change` any more then.

Comment: I much prefer the second option that doesn't use methods because I've learnt that the methods in the `computed` object only run when they have to, whereas those in the `methods` object always run. Even on something so tiny, it doesn't feel right to waste system resources

Comment: Wow! I'm learning a few things just by studying your code @connexo

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in my comment, you should be using the `methods` property for your `v-on:change` callback instead.

In a nutshell this means you have to change `computed` to `methods`

To understand the difference between the `computed` and `methods` property have a look at the vuejs documentation on both.

- [Computed Properties and Watchers](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html)
- [Events](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html)

Here is a working demo

```js
var main = new Vue({
  el: ".main-content",
  data: {
    heading: "First Vue Page",
    usdamount: 0,
    currencies: [{
        label: "GBP",
        rate: 0.7214,
        value: 0
      },
      {
        label: "EUR",
        rate: 0.80829,
        value: 0
      },
      {
        label: "CAD",
        rate: 1.2948,
        value: 0
      }
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    updateCurrencies: function() {
      console.log(this.usdamount);
      var usd = parseFloat(this.usdamount);
      for (var i = this.currencies.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        this.currencies[i].value = this.currencies[i].rate * usd;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.min.js"></script>

<section class="main-content">
  <h1>{{ heading }}</h1>
  <input type="number" v-on:change="updateCurrencies" v-model="usdamount">
  <p class="cur-value" v-for="cur in currencies">
    <strong>{{ cur.label }}</strong>: {{ cur.value }}
  </p>
</section>
```